# Python: Why does my function not display what's being returned in the interpreter?

Tags: python

## In the Python interactive interpreter:

I am importing a module that contains a class. These are the methods of that class (some of them):

```
    def do_api_call(self, params):
        return self.__apicall(params)
    
    def __apicall(self, params):
        return urllib2.urlopen(self.endpoint, params).read()
```

When I import the class and use the method do_api_call(), it doesn't output anything when it finishes running.

```
    def do_api_call(self, params):
        print(self.__apicall(params))
    
    def __apicall(self, params):
        return urllib2.urlopen(self.endpoint, params).read()
```

I create an instance of the class and run the method:

```
myapi = MyAPIClass()
myapi.do_api_call(params={'param': 'value'})
```

When I do the second version (note the print function) however, it outputs the HTML of the page that is being called.

**Why doesn't the first version output anything?** It's working (ie, it's getting the page and not raising any errors).

Comment: The behavior you describe seems impossible (the first version should instead display the `repr` of that HTML). Please edit to supply a complete interactive session (as small as feasible but reproducing this behavior) that I and others can copy and paste to check (and info on the Python version, OS version, etc).

Comment: That's what I thought too. Impossible. I'll get some more code up. The one thing that boggles me the most is that I'm literally taking the exact code twice with the only change being the print() function.

Comment: BTW, my version is 2.6 (latest whatever that is) and OS is Windows XP

Comment: Where did the other two answers go?

Comment: They were deleted. I deleted my own so as to avoid getting downvoted for an utterly unhelpful answer. It's probably the same for the other. They can be "undeleted", for what it's worth.

Comment: Oh lol, I thought I'd lost my mind or something. (I never down vote people for not being a help as I'm rarely helpful myself. Only if they don't attempt to answer the question do I.)

Comment: I deleted mine because at closer though what I posted didn't explain what you are seeing. I felt the urge to edit it to "I don't have any idea", but that wouldn't have been much of an answer :)

Comment: Your example call throws a TypeError for me, if endpoint is a http url ("sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict"). What kind of url are you using for `endpoint`?

Comment: It's https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp  (note StackOverflow strips the h t t p : // out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version only returns the value that you would like to see as the output. The second version actually prints this value.

If I were you, I would consider storing the return value of the call to the first version into a variable and printing that variable. That should solve your issue

Comment: Interactive interpreter. Works differently.

Comment: It's still not fixed but your idea confirmed my suspicion. I tried printing the result after saving result.read() to memory. It worked fine, then I tried returning the result and it did nothing (ie, one line says print(result) and the next line says print('result printed') and the next says return result. The output was first the HTML of the result, followed by "result printed". Nothing more was output.